# Is it possible to customize Validation for delete button of the PropertyFieldCollectionData control

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to customize the validation when user delete a record in PropertyFieldCollectionData control? I am trying to ask the user "Are you sure you want to delete " When user click the delete button.  It looks like there is no access to delete buton of the control in PropertyFieldCollectionData control. Any Work around for this?

[PropertyFieldCollectionData control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyFieldCollectionData control is a component provided by the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) that allows users to manage a collection of data. It provides a user interface for adding, editing, and removing items in the collection.

To customize the validation for the delete button in the PropertyFieldCollectionData control, you'll need to modify the source code of the control itself or create a custom version of the control.

Comment: Ok. Thank You! I hided the delete button and trying to implement delete function on a new field.